# `react-scripts test` return code always zero

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Is there anyone know how to make `yarn test` (or `npm test`) in a `react` app return non-zero code when there is failed test

In my project, executing `CI=true yarn test` return

```
Test Suites: 10 failed, 10 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.736s
Ran all test suites.
Done in 2.34s.
```

All tests failed. But the command returned zero-code.

This make `travis-ci` unable to detect failed test

Comment: After trying creating new app and try test `expect(true).toBe(false)`. `yarn test` exits with none-zero code as expected. Thus I think that `yarn test` actually treat only failed-by-result test as really **failed**. Tester errors (for example: empty test, exception of the tester function, ...) are counted as failed test but not make overall test script return non-zero code